# JavaDoc doesn't generate statement with full stop

Tags: java, javadoc

```
/**
 * for database operation.
 * main execute class is {@link org.test.toolkit.database.DefaultDbClient}
 *
 * @author  
 *
 */
```

Doesn't generate the statement: main execute class is....

[image: Screenshot of resulting JavaDoc]

```
/**
 * for database operation,
 * main execute class is {@link org.test.toolkit.database.DefaultDbClient}
 *
 * @author  
 *
 */
```

This generates the statement: main execute class is ....,

[image: Screenshot of resutling JavaDoc]

Why? Is it a JavaDoc bug or an IDE bug or my problem? The only difference is the end with `.` or `,`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JavaDoc uses [the first sentence](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#firstsentence) of the comment as the summary. A sentence ends with a fullstop `.`.

> This sentence ends at the first period that is followed by a blank, tab, or line terminator, or at the first tag [...].

Comment: " at the first period that is followed by a blank" I try one blank, it  can't be taken as first sentence but two blanks can? what's the reason? "jobs. main" vs "jobs.  main"